# Temporarily disable / bypass Middleware

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

In my Application I implemented a OAuth2-Server ([oauth2-server-laravel](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel)) in combination with a custom Authentication Package ([Sentinel by Cartalyst](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0#introduction)).

In my routes.php:

```
Route::group(['before' => 'oauth'], function()
{
    // ... some routes here
}
```

So the request must provide an authorization header or the application quits with an OAuthException.

Now I want to unittest my controllers. So I have to seed my database with a OAuth session and access token for every test.
Then overwrite the `call()`-method of `TestCase` and set the HTTP-Authorization Header with the Bearer Token.

Is there a way to disable or bypass middleware (in my case just for unit testing)?

In Laravel 4 they were called route filters and they were disabled in the testing environment anyway. You could also manually enable/disable them with `Route::enableFilters()`.

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this, my reading so far is that it's not possible to disable middleware in Laravel 5 the way that route filters were disabled in testing mode in Laravel 4. However I'm keen to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently with the release of Laravel 5.1 yesterday a `disableMiddleware()` method was added to the `TestCase` class, which now does exactly what I wanted.

Problem solved. :)

Comment: So just put `use WithoutMiddleware;` in your test case class

Comment: An improvement on this has been merged to framework that allows to disable a specific set of middlewares. see https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/18673

Answer (score 2):

The only answer that I could come up with was to put a bypass in the actual middleware itself.  For example:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // Don't validate authentication when testing.
    if (env('APP_ENV') === 'testing') {
        return $next($request);
    }
    // ... continue on to process the request
}
```

I don't like the idea of making the middleware dependent on the app environment but I couldn't see any other options.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a package that I worked on after having the same issue.

https://github.com/moon0326/FakeMiddleware